# Minimum split panel height in DevComponents

Tags: c#, wpf

Anybody knows about **DevComponents** WPF Componets?
I need to limit a **SplitPanel** to a *minimum height*, I don't know how to.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, the DevExpress support really rocks! I strongly recommend asking them directly.

Comment: It's from DevComponents, not DevExpress

Comment: Arrgh, sorry. I still suggest to switch to DevExpress, great suite.

Comment: Uwe, our support is much better than DevExpress ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact our support for help with any of our products. You can get all details here: http://www.devcomponents.com/support.aspx

SplitPanel is not component you would use stand-alone. It is part of our docking system. Likely what you are trying to do is set minimum width for dock windows when they are docked to left or right or minimum height if they are docked to top or bottom. If you are using **latest release** from our web site you can use *DockSite.MinimumDockWindowSize* property to suggest minimum size for all dock windows, or you can use *SplitPanel.MinimumDockWindowSize* to suggest minimum size for dock windows panel contains.

Here is more information on our docking controls from our Knowledge Base:

- [Key Wpf-Dock DockWindow Properties, Events and Commands](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=547)
- [How To Start Using Wpf-Dock Control](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=622)

Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way I have version 5 which seems not to have MinimumDockWindowSize! :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it have a `MinHeight` property you can set? I would assume it inherits from `FrameworkElement`, which has a `MinHeight` property

If not, wrap it in another Panel such as a `Grid` and set the `Grid.MinHeight`

```
<Grid MinHeight="100">
    <dev:SplitPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Then I'd recommend contacting their support to see if they have a resolution for the problem. Most UI controls inherit from `FrameworkElement`, which defines a `MinHeight` property. If the control is ignoring that property (or doesn't inherit from `FrameworkElement`), then it should at least be confined by the parent control's size. If that doesn't happen, it probably means the control explicitly sets its size somewhere and you'll have to look through the control's code to find out where.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi For some reason I am thinking you wanted MaxHeight, not MinHeight. To set MinHeight, you can also try setting the `VerticalAlignment` to Stretch and setting the `MinHeight` of the parent panel (I'll update my answer)

Comment: check above for reply from DevComponents, seems MinHeight is not working in their components! By the way seems you are a Microsoft fan.